# Recurrence Relations

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, recursion

How to calculate tribonacci number for very large n ( say 10^14 ) in best complexity. Tribonacci numbers are defined as `F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)+F(n-3)` with `F0=1, F1=2, F2=4`.

Or recurrence defined as 
`F(n)=aF(n-1)+bF(n-2)+cF(n-3)` with `F0=1, F1=2, F2=4`.

I want to Calculate nth term in log(n) just like nth Fibonacci number.

How can I generate the Base Matrix for using matrix exponentiation to calulate the nth 
term?

Previously I was trying to implement it using DP but as we cannot take array of such large size its not working fine. Similarly Recursion didn't  work here due to stack overflow for very large numbers of order of 10^14.

Comment: Well `f(n) = 1.1374515722826291096 * 1.8392867552141611326^n - 0.73735270576032767520^n * (0.24704361526838014667 sin(2.17623354549187039845 n) + 0.13745157228262910956 cos(2.17623354549187039845 n))` :p

Comment: write the program using MPI and become famous for releasing the largest tribonacci number to the world!

Comment: By "very large n", do you mean that the *value* will be ~10^14, or do you want the 10^14th term in the tribonacci sequence, i.e. F(10^14)?  That latter number will be absurdly large.

Comment: There's a [formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html) for the general term of the Tribonacci sequence (or any extension to the Fibonacci sequence, for that matter). I suggest you use that.

Comment: @EitanT, that suffers from numerical inaccuracy for large *n*.

Comment: @dbaupp can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @EitanT, if one is using floating point computations, there are the standard precision problems representing the irrational α, β and γ.

Comment: @dbaupp i don't think there was anything "numerical" about the formula

Comment: @pyCthon, which formula are you talking about?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *best* asymptotic complexity for tribonacci numbers will be  using a matrix exponentiation method like [the one for Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form). Specifically, written correctly, this is O(log n) integer operations, rather than O(n) (like the dynamic programming method) or O(3<sup>n</sup>) (like the naive solution).

The matrix of interest is

```
    [1, 1, 1]
M = [1, 0, 0]
    [0, 1, 0]
```

and the *n*th tribonacci number is in the upper left corner of *M<sup>n</sup>*. The matrix exponentiation must be computed [by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) to achieve log(n) complexity.

(for `F(n+3) = a F(n+2) + b F(n+1) + c F(n)`, the matrix is:

```
    [a, b, c]
M = [1, 0, 0]
    [0, 1, 0]
```

and the result is {F<sub>n+2</sub>,F<sub>n+1</sub>,F<sub>n</sub>} = M<sup>n</sup> {F<sub>2</sub>,F<sub>1</sub>,F<sub>0</sub>}, also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12333581/849891).)

Comment: I don't like the statement `The best complexiy`. You can find the number using a close formula, as shown by @KennyTM in comments, this will be `O(f(answer))`, where `f(answer)` is the complexity of your power function of the resulting number. There are other close formulas in [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html). Other then the first statement - I like this answer.

Comment: @amit, the complexity of that is still O(log n), since there is an exponentiation by n required, and that can't be done faster than O(log n), I believe.

Comment: Best *asymptotic* complexity != best complexity. [I sinned in using the asymptotic notation in the comment as well].

Comment: Yes. But your previous comment made me think of a different issue. Both are `O(logn)` assuming `O(1)` integer ops. However - this assumption is unrealistic for large numbers as the OP is after, since the number (answer) itself is `O(3^n)`, so you need `O(n)` bits to represent it - resulting in integer arithmetics to be `O(n)` itself - thus DP will be `O(n^2)`, and close formula/matrix will be `O(nlogn)`. Don't you agree?

Comment: Your edits makes the answer much better. I can now quitely +1 it for being both efficient and accurate.

Comment: @amit, yes, I do agree, and furthermore, the integer multiplications will be worse than O(n). (Thanks :) )

Comment: Can someone explain to me what I'm missing?  Trib(10^14) ~ 4*10^26464944348424, if my quick calculation is right.  [Although at these scales it scarcely matters how much I'm off by!]

Comment: @DSM, I guess that 10^14 was just an example of a large number... probably a little too large.

Comment: @dbaupp Can you specify which terms the numbers in the matrix are? for example M[0][0] is f(n). I need to know because in my problem, the tribonacci sequence starts with f(0) = -2, f(1) = -4, f(2) = -7

Comment: @Rushil, yes, `M[0][0]`. However, you will need to multiply the `M^n` matrix by a "initial conditions" matrix... I'm unsure what matrix should be.

Comment: that's what I'm looking for. Initial condition matrix..Isn't there any way to calculate it?

Comment: @Rushil, sorry, it's actually really obvious. You make a vector `v = [-7, -4, -2]`, and then `f(n) = (M^(n-2) * v)[0]`. (This actually holds for `n = 0, 1, 2` also, but it's probably easier to just special case them.)

Comment: the OP changed his question; now the top row in the matrix M should be `a b c`, I think.

Comment: @WillNess, yep, thanks for pointing it out. Adjusted the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

A Dynamic programming solution does NOT require 10^14 elements array. **It only requires 3**.

Note that each step is only using previous 3 elements, so for `F(1000)`, you really do not need `F(5)`.

You can simply override elements that are no longer needed, and regard them as a new number.

The `%` operator is your friend for this purpose.

Comment: its taking too much time too compute using O(n) I want algorithm which can compute in O(logn ) time ..

Comment: @RahulKumarDubey: Then use a close formula or [dbaupp suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12234153/572670). I was just answering your question, I thought DP is what you are after.