# Tribonacci series

Tags: c++, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recurrence Relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234066/recurrence-relations)

How do I find the n:th number in the tribonacci series?
I need and algorithm fast enough for `n` up to 10^15.

Tribonacci numbers are defined as **a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2) + a(n-3)** with a(0)=a(1)=0, a(2)=1.

Comment: What about this formula:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234066/recurrence-relations#comment16395223_12234066

Comment: this question should be in math.stackexchange?

Comment: There's not enough context. Are you finding them incrementally? Are you trying to determine a single particular one?

Comment: @oldrinb yes i am trying to determine a single one..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any sequence with a linear recurrence, the matrix exponentiation algorithm works.

If e.g. the sequence has the recurrence

```
a[k] = x*a[k-1] + y*a[k-2] + z*a[k-3]
```

for `k >= 3` and initial values `a[0], a[1], a[2]`, you obtain the triple `(a[n+2], a[n+1], a[n])` by multiplying

```
|x y z|^n  |a[2]|
|1 0 0|  * |a[1]|
|0 1 0|    |a[0]|
```

The matrix can be raised to the n<sup>th</sup> power using exponentiation by repeated squaring in `O(log n)` steps.